# Is it valid GET method in REST, that returns some set of data, but after a while, the dataset can be modified?

Tags: rest, http

I was reading about "idempotent methods", but not quite get it.

1.1. So the GET method must be idempotent.

1.2. An idempotent HTTP method is a HTTP method that can be called many times without different outcomes. It would not matter if the method is called only once, or ten times over. The result should be the same. - See more at: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/#sthash.hW6zSUi7.dpuf

Okay, that was theory. Now specific case:

2.1. I have exposed a GET method, that return all records in DB.

2.2. Somebody called this method and it returned 1000 results.

2.3. The application is running, so in a few minutes I have 1001 records in the DB.

2.4. Somebody (maybe the same caller) called this method again and now it returned 1001 results.

Is mine GET method is still idempotent or it should be changed to POST?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Because the GET is not changing the resource. That's the distinction.

Consider:

```
GET /currenttime
```

Perfectly valid request, idempotent, but you'll get a new answer pretty much every time you call it.

Answer (score 2):

> An idempotent HTTP method is a HTTP method that can be called many times without different outcomes. It would not matter if the method is called only once, or ten times over. The result should be the same.

The opening sentence is somewhat unfortunate but the rest explains it pretty clearly.

The key point to note here is that the outcome may not be altered by any number of subsequent calls of the same method. The state of the resource, a represantation of which you're `GET`ting is free to be changed by other means though.

In your example it isn't the `GET` request that's changing the state of the database. It's an external factor.

> Is my GET method is still idempotent or it should be changed to POST?

Yes, the way you describe it, it's both idempotent and safe as it does not modify the state of your resources and it will always yield the same result provided that other parties do not alter the resource state between calls. Calling it does not affect the result of calling it.